# independence to conditional independence knowing conditional pdf & parameter pdf

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, parameter-estimation

Let $Y_k,k=1,\dotsc,n$ be iid RVs. Given $\vartheta$ each $Y_k$ has pdf $f_{Y_k|\vartheta}(y_k|\theta)=\frac{\theta}{2}e^{-\theta |y_k|}$. $\vartheta$ has the marginal pdf $f_\vartheta(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ on $[1,e]$ and $0$ otherwise. Prove or disprove: $Y_k|\vartheta,k=1,\dotsc,n$ are independent.

---

I am not sure if there is enough information here. I have found out that $Y_k$ is not independent of $\vartheta$ since with some multiplication and integration: $f_{Y_k,\vartheta}(y,\theta)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\theta|y|}$ but $f_{Y_k}(y)= \frac{e^{-|y|}-e^{-e|y|}}{2|y|}$. This precludes taking an easy route.

My difficulty is that I don't know how to find for example $f_{Y_1,Y_2|\vartheta}(y_1,y_2|\theta)$ to compare it to $f_{Y_1|\vartheta}(y_1|\theta)f_{Y_2|\vartheta}(y_2|\theta)$.

If some additional minor assumptions need to be put in place to proceed that is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that if they were independent conditional on $\theta$, it would be impossible that they were unconditionally independent.

Basically, knowing the values of a subset of the $Y_i$ would allow us to do inference on $\theta$ via the conditional distribution. Our knowledge of that subset certainly changes our distributional outlook for the unobserved subset, since if we estimate a large $\theta\approx e,$ we would expect smaller values for the unobserved $Y$ then we would had we not observed the other $Y$ (since we know they're i.i.d. conditional on theta, which we have a distribution for from our inference). This means that the $Y_i$ are unconditionally dependent on each other.

Comment: Ah yes, very simple intuition. Thank you! Also if $f_\vartheta(\theta)$ here is changed to $e^{-\theta}$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ it becomes easy to verify since the integrals are just gamma function integrals.

Comment: Is it possible to verify in generality that $f(\vec{y} | \theta)= \prod^n_{k=1} f(y_k|\theta) \Rightarrow f(\vec{y}) \neq \prod^n_{k=1} f(y_k)$, where $f(y_k | \theta)$ is some pdf with a parameter $\theta$?

Comment: @IlyaKavalerov Not sure. If the distribution doesn't actually depend on $\theta$ then it's possible (in fact required). So I would guess there is some kind of identification requirement for $\theta$ needed.

Comment: @IlyaKavalerov The crux is when it's possible for $\int (\prod_i f(x_i|\theta) )p(\theta) d\theta = \prod_i \int f(x_i|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta$. Obviously when $f(x_i|\theta)$ does not depend on $\theta$ or when $P(\theta) = \delta(\theta-\theta_0).$ Other possibilities aren't so clear (but maybe it's obvious and I'm not seeing it). Maybe looking at distributions $p(\theta)$ where $\theta$ takes on a finite number of values would be elucidating.

Comment: Maybe my last question is preposterous since I am asking to compare $\prod_{k=1}^n f(y_k) = \prod_{k=1}^n \int_\Theta f(y_k|\theta)f(\theta)d\theta$ with $f(\vec{y})=\int_\Theta f(\theta) [\prod_{k=1}^n f(y_k|\theta)]d\theta$. Thanks for your help! edit: whoops you beat me to it! Thank you for all the follow ups!

Comment: @IlyaKavalerov  Not preposterous at all, it's natural to ask about the exact conditions under which the intuition holds (since there are some limiting cases where it doesn't). No prob.